# Hibernate criteria API invocation order using key(), value() methods of the MapJoin interface

Tags: hibernate, jpa, dictionary, one-to-many, criteria-api

I've a field in a `Person` entity that is modeled as map.

```
@Entity
public class Person{

    @OneToMany
    @MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public Map<PhoneType, PhoneNumber> phones;
```

`PhoneType` is an enum, `PhoneNumber` is an entity. According to how I understand the criteria API the following code should work:

```
public List<Object> getPersonPhonesCriteria(){
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Object> cq = cb.createQuery();
    Root<Person> person = cq.from(Person.class);
    MapJoin<Person,PhoneType,PhoneNumber> phones = person.joinMap("phones");

    cq.multiselect(person.get("firstName"), phones.key(), phones.value());

    TypedQuery<Object> q = em.createQuery(cq);
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

but I get the following error:

```
ERROR 6160 --- [main] o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter : node did not reference a map    
antlr.SemanticException: node did not reference a map
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.validateMapPropertyExpression(HqlSqlWalker.java:1336) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
```

With an **inverse invocation order** of the `key()` and `value()` methods in the `multiselect` it suddenly works:

```
cq.multiselect(person.get("firstName"), phones.value(), phones.key());
```

It nearly drove me nuts. Can anybody explain why the `multiselect` works in one case and in the other not?

Comment: I honestly would believe it shouldn't matter to my understanding.  I would put in a JIRA ticket for this problem as it seems more like a bug to me.

Comment: I thought into the same direction. I think I'll give it a try with EclipseLink and / or OpenJPA to check the behavior before I raise the ticket.

Comment: try using Metamodel: `person.join(Person_.phones)`, in some special case, maybe this one too, it's determinant with Hibernate